# Fastboot not working on Sony Xperia M

Tags: fastboot, 4.3-jelly-bean, sony-xperia

I'm using Xperia M and I have installed ADB and turned on USB debugging, turned off my mobile, then hold the volume up button and connected the USB.

I typed `fastboot devices` in cmd where I have my `fastboot.exe`, but it didn't type anything. No "(waiting for device)", no error, just nothing. The light on my mobile is blue like it has to be but it just not typing anything.

How to use fastboot on Xperia M?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed [Google USB Driver](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html)? Try reconnecting your phone then.

Make sure you are following every step of [this guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2484428), especially:

- making backup of IMEI and DRM keys
- running `fastboot.exe -i 0x0fce getvar version` command